# Nested pivot columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2014

I have a table sales:

```
SalesID. Date. Geography

1.       2020-01.  Italy
1.       2020-01.  France
1.       2020-01.  UK
2.       2020-02.  Italy
2.       2002-02.  Canada
3.       2002-08.  France
```

I would like to display only top 2 Geography and pivot:

Expected result:

```
SalesID.   Date. Geography 1.    Geography2.
1.      2020-01. Italy. France

2.     2020-02.  Italy.  France.
3.    2020-08.    France
```

What I try so far https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=565f80f146fe2a72096b31fc0baba3ad

How to modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select t.sales_id,
       date, 
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN geography END) AS geography1,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN geography END) AS geography2
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by t.sales_id, date order by t.date) as rn
FROM your_table t) t
GROUP BY t.sales_id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need a column that defines the ordering of the rows - I assumed `ordering_id`. Then, you can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation.

```
select saleid, date,
    max(case when rn = 1 then geography end) as geography1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then geography end) as geography2
from (
    select t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by saleid, date order by ordering_id) as rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn <= 2
group by saleid, date
```